# display only one point for each ID

Tags: qgis

I'm working with a point layer (many many features) that has some attributes, like the elevation of each point.

I created a polygon grid (5 km x 5 km each cell) with an unique ID and I made an intersection of the point with this polygon. This way each point that belong to a certain cell has now the unique ID.

[image]

Now, how can I display only the point with the maximum elevation for each different IDs? What is the expression I have to put in the field calculator of the rule renderer?

So in other word, how can I put into formula something like:

```
for each "ID" show max("ele_feet")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved not directly in QGIS but importing the layer in SpatiaLite and then using an SQL statement like this:

```
select name, max(ele) as ele, geom, pk as pk
from layer_id
group by id
```

Then I imported the query layer with DB Manager of QGIS.

BTW, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510185/select-max-value-of-each-group) answer

Hoping this could help other people.

Comment: Well done buddy! Wasn't sure if this was possible in the Field Calculator, infact I'm still not sure!